# rename missing from light bulb visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2017 community to develop C# program.

Before, whenever I change the declaration of a variable for example:
private decmial? _abc;
To
private decmial? _aBC;
There will be a light Bulb shows up nearby, and I can do rename from there, so all the usage of the same variable will be renamed.

However, I don't find this menu item from the light bulb anymore, what I see now is only two options:
Encapsulate field:'_aBC' (and user property)
Encapsulate field:'_aBc' (but still use field)

Does any one know how to get the "Rename" option back?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `Ctrl + R` `Ctrl + R` work? You have to highlight the symbol, and then use the keyboard shortcut twice. Should work. Looking into the issue now.

Comment: @PSGuy No "Ctrl+R" doesn't work. I have been using this feature for a few years, this is first time I see it disappear, and you actually don't need to highlight the variable, as long as your cursor is on the variable is OK.  I should be able to open the light bulb menu(Quick Action), but either click it or press(Alt + Enter).

Comment: I think using Ctrl + R requires two... either way, I think this is usually from a Roslyn extension crashing.

Comment: Did you install in plugin. Example: ReSharper or something else? Sometimes, the 3rd party plugins can mess up with  default VS tooling/ properties

Comment: I don't see any newly installed extension, the only thing I did today on this computer is: I copied over a project that use nunit and moq package, and after I opened the project, I use Nuget Package Manager to install nUnit and Moq on the project.  Maybe that mess up with some thing. @AnkitVijay

Comment: Can you go to tools -> Options -> Keyboard. Search for command Refractor.Rename and see what is the shortcut shown?

Comment: @AnkitVijay "Refactor.Rename" is the correct spelling.

Comment: @AnkitVijay it shows: Ctrl+R

Comment: HI @JinTiger did you try Ctrl+R to see if it works?

Comment: @AnkitVijay It works, but I still want the "Quick Action" to contain the "Rename" option.  Thanks for your response